# Add nexentastor to domain (ldap/samba)

Tags: linux, samba, solaris, nexenta, illumos

I have PDC on LDAP/SAMBA 3.x on CentOS 5.
Domain memberships - Linux/Windows (Xp..7).
For add computer account in PDC i run (on PDC)

```
smbldap-useradd -w workstationname
```

on the linux,

- configure smb.conf
- smbpasswd -w password_for_ldap_admin
- net join -S PDC_NAME -U domainadmin

Welcome to domain..

At now, i have one NexentaStor OS machine (v40-0-18, beta)

```
uname -a
SunOS gis 5.11 288c5cb8e28a i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
```

i am to installed samba

```
apt-cache show service-network-samba

Package: service-network-samba
Version: 1.1.1
Architecture: solaris-i386
```

make machine account on PDC (`smbldap-useradd -w nexenta`), configured smb.conf and try add to domain

```
net join -S ARMADA

Enter root's password:
Could not connect to server ARMADA
The username or password was not correct.
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

error log on PDC

```
[2013/07/18 15:59:41,  0] rpc_server/srv_netlog_nt.c:336(get_md4pw)
  get_md4pw: Workstation NEXENTA$: no account in domain
[2013/07/18 15:59:41,  0] rpc_server/srv_netlog_nt.c:584(_netr_ServerAuthenticate3)
  _netr_ServerAuthenticate2: failed to get machine password for account NEXENTA$: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2013/07/18 15:59:41,  0] rpc_server/srv_netlog_nt.c:336(get_md4pw)
  get_md4pw: Workstation NEXENTA$: no account in domain
[2013/07/18 15:59:41,  0] rpc_server/srv_netlog_nt.c:584(_netr_ServerAuthenticate3)
  _netr_ServerAuthenticate2: failed to get machine password for account NEXENTA$: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

what i doing wrong? Always work fine, but with nexenta dont work..

Answer (score 0):

You should create machine account for the NEXENTA before you can add it to the domain

```
# smbldap-useradd -w NEXENTA
```

Comment: i do it, but ..

Comment: Could you show the output of smbldap-usershow NEXENTA$

Comment: see below

    `[root@armada ~]# smbldap-usershow NEXENTA$
    dn: uid=nexenta$,ou=Computers,dc=geo,dc=org
    objectClass: top,account,posixAccount
    cn: nexenta$
    uid: nexenta$
    uidNumber: 1686
    gidNumber: 515
    homeDirectory: /dev/null
    loginShell: /bin/false
    description: Computer
    gecos: Computer`

Comment: Try the following # smbldap-userdel NEXENTA$  # smbldap-useradd -W -g 515 NEXENTA

Comment: [root@armada ~]# smbldap-useradd -W -g 515 NEXENTA

Comment: [root@armada ~]# smbldap-usershow NEXENTA$
dn: uid=NEXENTA$,ou=Computers,dc=geo,dc=org
objectClass: posixAccount,account,sambaSAMAccount,top
cn: NEXENTA$
uid: NEXENTA$
uidNumber: 1687
gidNumber: 515
homeDirectory: /dev/null
loginShell: /bin/false
description: Computer
gecos: Computer
sambaLogonTime: 0
sambaLogoffTime: 2147483647
sambaKickoffTime: 2147483647
sambaPwdMustChange: 2147483647
sambaPwdLastSet: 1374165166
sambaAcctFlags: [W]
sambaSID: S-1-5-21-2068682600-2350025889-3278183345-4374
sambaPrimaryGroupSID: S-1-5-21-2068682600-2350025889-3278183345-515
displayName: NEXENTA$

Comment: error still the same?

Comment: yes (( `root@gis:/volumes/RZ2/BAZA# net join -S ARMADA
Enter root's password:
Could not connect to server ARMADA
The username or password was not correct.
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`

Comment: PDC side log file `[root@armada ~]# tail -f /var/log/samba/log.nexenta
[2013/07/19 09:46:54,  0] rpc_server/srv_netlog_nt.c:584(_netr_ServerAuthenticate3)
  _netr_ServerAuthenticate2: failed to get machine password for account NEXENTA$: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[2013/07/19 09:47:35,  0] rpc_server/srv_netlog_nt.c:387(get_md4pw)
  get_md4pw: Workstation NEXENTA$: account does not have a password
[2013/07/19 09:47:35,  0] `

Comment: Could you show me # net rpc info -U root and then try # net rpc join -U domain_admin -d 7 NEXENTA

Comment: Sorry for delay @ALex_hha `net rpc info -U root
Enter root's password:
Could not connect to server ARMADA
The username or password was not correct.
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`

Comment: net rpc join -U domain_admin -d 7 NEXENTA see [http://pastebin.com/VtEFK8nR](http://pastebin.com/VtEFK8nR)